# Send to New Folder Vista

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, send-to

In explorer I'd like to be able to highlight a group of icons and then 
right click-> send to-> New Folder. How can I accomplish this? Bonus points if the focus is on the folder name after this completes.

Answer (score 1):

See this, Right click copy to, move to

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-copy-to-move-to-on-windows-vista-right-click-menu/

You would then need to select the folder location and then click the "Make new folder" button

Comment: I still feel this can be done with less effort

Comment: That still takes two steps. Is there anyway to Add that "Send to New Folder" functionality? One click and you have moved all files into a new folder, versus the ugly having to select something from a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via the 'Edit' menu item in Vista. First make the menu bar visible via the 'Organize' icon on the top left of an Explorer window >> then select Layout >> Menu Bar.

Then after highlighting what you want click 'Edit' >> 'Copy To Folder' or 'Move To Folder'.

You can create a new folder from that explorer pop up window thereafter.

Here's a detailed step by step guide:

[Vista's Hidden Copy To and Move To Folder Commands](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=556)